# Laravel API throws FileNotFoundException when accessed through an android app

Tags: filenotfoundexception, laravel-5

I'm working on an API using Laravel 5.2. I have disabled the csrf token by commenting `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` in `kernel.php`. If I access my API with postman everything works like charm but when using an android app I get `FileNotFoundException`. Please help. I can post the code and other details if you want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tell more about your Android app? I suppose that you're using Postman from the same pc as your API.

Do you simulate the Android app, or do you use an real Android device with the app installed?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was on the android side.... Sorry

Comment: @Schellingert : Is there anyway i can connect with you, apart from stackoverflow, like facebook or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry It was an issue on the android side not on Laravel. It is resolved now.

The issue was that I was setting the HTTP CODES myself in Laravel. So the problem was If i set a code in range 4XX( like 404), android will consider it as an error and show `fileNotFoundException` and neglect the stream in the connection. So changing `getInputStream` to `getErrorStream` resolved the problem. `getErrorStream` reads the stream even if the response code is some kind of error like 404,422 ,etc. I hope the explanation is sufficient.